# pyspark - using MatrixFactorizationModel in RDD's map function

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

I have this model:

```
from pyspark.mllib.recommendation import ALS

model = ALS.trainImplicit(ratings,
                              rank,
                              seed=seed,
                              iterations=iterations,
                              lambda_=regularization_parameter,
                              alpha=alpha)
```

I have successfully used it to recommend users to all product with the simple approach:

```
recRDD = model.recommendUsersForProducts(number_recs)
```

Now if I just want to recommend to a set of items, I first load the target items:

```
target_items = sc.textFile(items_source)
```

And then map the `recommendUsers()` function like this:

```
recRDD = target_items.map(lambda x: model.recommendUsers(int(x), number_recs))
```

This fails after any action I try, with the following error:

```
It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast variable, action, or transformation. SparkContext can only be used on the driver, not in code that it run on workers. For more information, see SPARK-5063.
```

I'm trying this locally so I'm not sure if this error persists when on client or cluster mode. I have tried to broadcast the `model`, which only makes this same error when trying to broadcast instead.

Am I thinking straight? I could eventually just recommend for all and then filter, but I'm really trying to avoid recommending for every item due the large amount of them.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to call `recommendUsers` from the workers because it ultimately calls `callJavaFunc` which needs the SparkContext as an argument. If `target_items` is sufficiently small you could call `recommendUsers` in a loop on the driver (this would be the opposite extreme of predicting for all users and then filtering).

Alternatively, have you looked at [`predictAll`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html#module-pyspark.mllib.recommendation)? Roughly speaking, you could run predictions for all users for the target items, and then rank them yourself.

Comment: The `predictAll` suggestion seems a good idea! At least it might avoid some work.
Meanwhile I have actually been looping the target set in the driver, just a shame not to make the best use of Spark here...